# Android not showing Whatsapp and Telegram suggestions for a contact

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, telegram

I have tried to search this I swear. on my S20, if you clicked on a contact it would suggest/show you if a contact has whatsapp or telegram. It was a shortcut even. my S22, it doesnt show anything but the number below the name and history. Contacts are synced via whatsapp, I believe it is some setting on my droid, not the other communication apps. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd assume both are about Samsung's built-in Contacts app, but just to be sure, are both the same Contacts app and the same version?